# phpmyadmin download SHA256 disagreement

Tags: security, download, phpmyadmin, sha256

The current phpmyadmin tar download SHA256 hash does not match the download site  value. The published hash for ver 4.9.3 is `f75c5e11b076176436653c6138d8185b0351b02a1bf8c5069ec8d0af254911df` but I get this :

```
downloads % shasum -a 256 phpMyAdmin-4.9.3-english.tar
514219cdf85819748e5f89584ccb5e0d181c27262f7da8950918133706d3d8fe.
```

Unfortunately the tar unpacked automatically. Do I now have a hacked file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have another download, 
It looks like you have downloaded this package **phpMyAdmin-4.9.3-english.tar.gz** when i generate SHA256 i got `f75c5e11b076176436653c6138d8185b0351b02a1bf8c5069ec8d0af254911df` which is same as published on [website](https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.9.3/phpMyAdmin-4.9.3-english.tar.gz.sha256).

Even i checked all 4.9.3 versions hash but could not find your package hash `514219cdf85819748e5f89584ccb5e0d181c27262f7da8950918133706d3d8fe`

Answer (score 0):

With Jaikey Sarraf's help I found my problem. After the the .tar.gz file is downloaded macOS Catalina immediately unpacked the .tar.gz and trashed it replacing it with just the .tar. I did not notice the switch so did SHA156 on the .tar which created my problem. Dragging the .gz out of trash and running SHA256 gives the correct hash.

Answer (score 0):

We had caching issues with our CDN and now they are solved

Please try again and report if you find that the hash does not match

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website/issues/84